# How to select rows between rows matching certain conditions and perform checks R

Tags: r

I need to perform a check on rows between rows that match a certain condition per grouping, and store the value in a new column. The catch is that I will be text-matching the in-between rows to the row that meets the condition and counting how many rows were between the condition row and the matched row. If there isn't a row that matches between the condition row and the end of the group or the next condition row, then that value is just -1.

```
 # Determine rows where num = 1
 num_ind<- which(df$num==1)  

 # Get up to 5 following rows between rows where num = 1 
 df<- df[unique(sort(num_ind + rep(0:5, each = length(num_ind)))),]



**Example data:**  
id  id2   num  text   text2  
1    1     1    "a"     ""  
1    1     0    ""    "b"  
1    1     0    ""    "a"  
1    1     1    ""     ""  
1    2     1    "a"     ""  
1    2     0    ""    "b"  
1    2     0    ""    "b"  
1    2     0    ""    "b"  
2    1     0    ""    "a"  
2    1     0    ""    "b"  
2    1     0    ""    "b"  
3    1     1    ""     ""  
......


 # for each group in grouped_by(id,id2)
 # get rows in between rows where num = 1
 # compare the text2 in each following row to text in the num=1 row
 # create a column that shows how many following rows that takes
 # if there isn't a match, that value would be -1



**Expected output:**  
id  id2   num  text   text2  check  
1    1     1    "a"     ""     2  
1    1     0    ""    "b"      NA  
1    1     0    ""    "a"      NA  
1    1     1    "a"    ""      -1  
1    2     1    "a"    ""      4  
1    2     0    ""    "b"      NA  
1    2     0    ""    "b"      NA  
1    2     0    ""    "b"      NA  
1    2     0    ""    "a"      NA  
2    1     1    "b"    ""      2  
2    1     0    ""    "a"      NA  
2    1     0    ""    "b"      NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the data.table library for this:

```
df = data.table(df)                                       # Make df a data table
df$RowID = 1:nrow(df)                                     # Add a row ID column
d1 = data.table(df[num==1])                               # Second data table, containing only the rows with num = 1
d1 = d1[df,on = c("id","id2",text = "text2")]             # Join the two data tables
d1 = d1[i.num==0 & i.RowID > RowID & i.RowID < RowID + 5] # Get only the candidate rows
dFinal = d1[,.(check = min(i.RowID-RowID)),by='RowID']    # Find which match came first
df = dFinal[df,on="RowID"]                                # Join the tables
df[num==1 & is.na(check),check:=-1]                       # Fill empty checks where num = 1 with value -1
```

There are several ways to condense this further and reduce caching, but I kept it spread out for readability and commenting. I would suggest going through this row by row to understand each piece.